# while in debug mode: source not found in android email reading application

Tags: android

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
Store store;
store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", user, password);
```

I am trying to write an Android app which will read gmail emails. While i have it in debug mode I am getting an error "source not found" when I step over:

```
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", user, password);
```

I really dont know what to do next. Is there a specific library I need to link to?

Here is a screen shot of my code in debug mode with a breakpoint on the line which will trigger this error:
[image]

now I hit F5 and I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: nice now I have your gmail username and password thanks

Comment: its just a dummy account which I use for this test... I dont care who uses it.

Comment: i am going to guess, that I need to attach some jar file..